# How to read a variable containing HTML content and store it in another variable without tags?

Tags: php, html, string, hyperlink

I have a PHP string variable such as:

```
$str="<a href='abc.com'>Click-me-here</a><br/><p style='color:white;'>New Paragraph</p>";
```

I want this variable to be read as HTML content and store it in different variable. Ex: my $htmlstr should contain:

```
console.log($htmlstr) => Click-me-here
                         New Paragraph.
```

So my question is how to read $str containing HTML content(link) and store them in $htmlstr as clickable link.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Can you edit the question to include all the thngs that you have tried and explain any problems?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the question from the title: use strip_tags function https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

```
php > $str="<a href='abc.com'>Click-me-here</a><br/><p style='color:white;'>New Paragraph</p>";

// if you need to extract text without html tags
php > var_dump(strip_tags($str));
string(26) "Click-me-hereNew Paragraph"

// if you need extract the text and want to leave new lines (br)
php > var_dump(strip_tags($str, '<br>'));
string(31) "Click-me-here<br/>New Paragraph"

// if you need extract the text and want to have new lines as new line character (not html)
php > var_dump(str_replace('<br/>', PHP_EOL, strip_tags($str, '<br>')));
string(27) "Click-me-here
New Paragraph"
```